Proof of the Open Mapping Theorem.
I have an exercise where I must prove the following theorem:

Theorem:   Let $X$ and $Y$ two Banach spaces, let $l$ a continuous surjectivity linear mapping between $X$ and $Y$. Now, for every open $U$ of the topological space $(X, \tau (\left\| \cdot \right\|_X)  )$, we have that $l(U)$ is too open.

Proof:
1-  As $l$ is surjective we know that $l(X)=Y$. Now, according to the first theorem of Isomorphism, we know that there exists an isomorphism $ l': X/\ker(l) \mapsto l(X)=Y$.
2- It is easy to note that $l'$ is still a linear continuous mapping (more precisally $ l' \in L(X/\ker(l) ; Y) $). Moreover, we know from here that $l'^{-1}$ is too continuous.
Then $l'$ is a homeomorphism from $X/\ker(l)$ to $Y$.
3- As $l'$ is a homeomorphism it means directly that $\forall U' \in (X/\ker(l), \tau (\left\| \cdot \right\|_X)  ) \Rightarrow l'(U') $ is too an open set of $(Y, \tau (\left\| \cdot \right\|_Y)  )$.
4- As any open set $U'$ correspond only to an open set $U \in (X, \tau (\left\| \cdot \right\|_X)  )$, that naturally verify too $l(U)=l'(U')$.
Q.E.D.
Is this correct?
Thank you.

Please read tag descriptions. Tag description for "theorem-provers": "Automatic proof checkers verify the validity of formal proofs, while proof assistants aid in the construction of formal proofs. Some popular systems: Mizar, Coq, Isabelle.".

Which "first isomorphism theorem" are you referring to? I'm only aware of versions for modules, groups and rings but not for Banach spaces. Do you have a reference?

Also, what exactly do you mean by isomorphism? Linear bijection? Linear bijection that is also a homeomorphism?

@Smiley1000 ok i changed it for proof-verificatioon that is for "For questions concerning a specific proof or a specific solution, asking for verification, identifying errors, suggestions for improvement, etc. "

You're also citing https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2443553/491450 . To prove the claim in that post, one literally uses the open mapping theorem, which is what you're trying to show. So your argument is circular.

If I remember correctly, the open mapping theorem and the closed graph theorem are basically equivalent and are both based on the Baire category theorem. Your argument should therefore make some reference to the Baire category theorem.

@Smiley1000 Thk for your answer quickly the first isomorphism theorem states that given two groups $G$ anf $G'$ a normal group $N$ of $G$ and a group morphism $\phi: G \to G'$ then it exists an isomorphisme $\phi" : G/N \to\phi(G) \subseteq G' $ . I hop I ve been clear enough.

@Smiley1000 Concerning the circular argument you are right but I think that there is an other way of proving that $l'^{-1}$ is continuous, it is simply not the point of my question here so i just remembered this theorem that I used.

And why is this group homomorphism $X / \operatorname{ker}(l) \to Y$ linear?

@Smiley1000 Frst thk for spending time on my question. Secondly english is not my mother tongue so i thk that what you call homomorphism is called morphism for me. Thirdly In this question i did not spend a lot of time on the algebric things but it seems to me pretty obvious (maybe i am wrong). I am going to edit my question in order to add those details.

@Smiley1000 the fact that $l'$ is linear came directly from the first isomorphism theorem. Indeed linear mapping are just a name give to specific morphism on specific group. More precisally linear mapping are the group morphism of the group that are the vector space. In other words saying here that $l'$ is a group morphism is equivalent of saying that $l'$ is a linear mapping. Simply here our group is a vector space $X$ with the operation $+$.

That's not correct, there are group homomorphisms $V \to W$ that are not linear. For example, take $K = V = W = \mathbb{R}$. Then we can also consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. It has a basis $B$. Now take $b_1 \neq b_2 \in B$ and the linear map from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself that swaps $b_1$ and $b_2$. This is a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear map and hence a group homomorphism. However, it is clearly not $\mathbb{R}$-linear. We have exhibited a group homomorphism from $V$ to $W$ that is not $K$-linear.

The first isomorphism theorem is theorem A from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems (for vector spaces we can use the statement for modules, although I find it more insightful to think of the general case in universal algebra). So the linearity of $l'$ does come from this theorem, but not in its group form. Just stating the group form is not enough!

You have proven that the bounded inverse theorem implies the open mapping theorem. This reduction is correct (and is essentially the one noted in the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(functional_analysis) right under the statement of the bounded inverse theorem), but, as noted in the comments, the bounded inverse theorem is usually derived as a corollary to the open mapping theorem. So this does not really constitute a full proof of the bounded inverse theorem.
Some points that you might wish to be a little more careful about:

Showing that an open $U$ corresponds to an open $U'$ requires the that the quotient map be open. This is true for topological groups in general, but not for topological spaces.
The isomorphism theorem gives you that $l'$ is a linear isomorphism, not that it is continuous. Continuity follows from a result about quotient topologies. (Hiding this behind the phrase "It is easy to note that ..." is not optimal proof writing).
You have not required surjectivity in the statement of the theorem. This is clearly required (and indeed you use it).

EDIT: Since there was some confusion about the first isomorphism theorem:

You should be explicit about the fact that it is not enough to use the first isomorphism theorem for groups, you need to use a version that applies to vector spaces!


Concerning surjectivity You re right someone edited the message and remove this part
